# best practices in scaling sitecore

Tags: azure, scaling

What are the best best practices on scaling sitecore 8 worldwide on Azure?

https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/scaling_guide_sc70_a4.pdf

Thanks
Bart

Comment: Are you talking about Sitecore Azure or simple idea of get Virtual Machines in Azure and install Sitecore on them?

Comment: Sorry Bart, this is a little too broad. If you have a more specific question about the best practices, it might work better in this format.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that since you've linked the Scaling Guide that you're using VMs in Azure. If the site leans heavily towards consumption-oriented, I would put a number of content delivery servers behind a load balancer in Azure and use the Azure CDN to distribute content worldwide. Make sure that you have the appropriate caching turned on in Sitecore as well and performance/load test your site extensively.

You can find more details around Azure CDN here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-overview/